# Spring JDBC Template Query with String/Varchar parameters

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String query = "select a.alert_id from alert a where (alert.last_execution is null or trunc(alert.last_execution) < to_date(?, 'dd/MM/yyyy') ) and alert.frequency = ?";
jdbcTemplate.query(query, new Object[] {sdf.format(new Date()), "DAILY"}, new AlertRowMapper())
```

It retuns an exception in the query line:

SQL state [99999]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)

Do someone know why it is not working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the Date object directly into the `jdbcTemplate` parameter and remove the `to_date()` portion from your query. Spring should convert data types automatically rather than you converting to and from Strings in the app.

Comment: alert_id number(19);
frequency varchar2(50);
last_execution timestamp(0) with time zone;

Comment: this workaround worked: final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  return jdbcTemplate.query(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
      public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException {
          PreparedStatement alertableAlertsQuery = con.prepareStatement(queryAlertableAlerts);
          alertableAlertsQuery.setString(1, sdf.format(lastExecutionLimit));
          alertableAlertsQuery.setString(2, String.valueOf(frequencyType)); 
          return alertableAlertsQuery;
      }
  },  new AlertRowMapper(jdbcTemplate, failedAlerts));

Comment: but is ugly I would like to have it working with new Object[]{params} stuff

Comment: I have just realised in your first example you do not define what the types are for your query. `See query(String sql, Object[] args, int[] argTypes, RowCallbackHandler rch)`.